# How can i validate the user's identity when i want to use the refresh token to get a new access token after the previous access token expired?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Suppose I develop a website which integrate Google login.

When a user login with Google, I got an authorization code.

In the backend of the website, I use the authorization code to get the access_token and refresh_token. And return the access_token to the frontend.

And the website provide a function to get user's Google info through the access_token.

When the access_token expired, If the user use that function, the backend use the access_token request Google API will return token expired.

I can use the user's refresh_token stored in backend to request s new access_token.

But how can I validate the request is invoked by the refresh_token's owner?

Answer (score 1):

Once the original authentication token has been issued, it is the bearer's responsibility to keep it secure, and not the servers.

When issuing refresh tokens, the cone of responsibility remains with the bearer.

Dealing with the server-side security of tokens is covered by

> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-binding